# VBA Excel wrong order of IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I have another problem related to IF statement.

I have the following code:

```
 Sub BOMNewRow()
    If Range("D38").Value <> "" Or Range("C38") <> "x" Or Range("C38") <> "0" Then
    'Inserting new Core Drill row + formula autofill from the previous one
      Range("A38").EntireRow.Insert
      Range("A38").Value = "First Core drill into building or existing chamber (per event)"
      Range("B38").Value = "Sitec"
    
      If Range("D39").Value Like "*2*" Or Range("C39").Value = 2 Then
        Range("C38").Value = 2
      Else
        Range("C38").Value = 1
      End If
    
     Range("E38").Value = 100.39
     Range("F37").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F37:F38"), Type:=xlFillDefault
   'customizing new row
    With Range("A38:B38,D38:F38")
      .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
      .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
   End With
   With Range("C38")
      .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
   End With
    Else
   Call AuditCheck   'go straight away to the BoM audit control
'Taking a look on one of the audit cell
  End If
 If Range("C39").Value <> "x" Or Range("C39").Value <> "0" Then
  Range("C39").Value = "x"
  Range("D38").Value = Range("D39")
Call New_version2
Sheets("BoM").Activate
 Else
   Call AuditCheck
End If
Range("A43").Select
End Sub
```

What I intend to do is:

- insert the new row 38 and customize it - this is done by my first IF statement.
- run the second IF statement based on the cell C39, which doesn't work.

If previously I had the X value in the cell C38, now when I inserted a new row the second IF statement still executes the process for value C39, which is X.
[image].

It looks like I don't understand the if statement order within the macro.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not clear the contents of the new row?

Comment: Because I can't have empty spaces. Clearing the row it will remain it empty

Comment: You should get in the habit of consistently indenting your code to make it more readable. I don't think I understand your problem actually.

Comment: I changed my question description a bit.

Comment: Most confusion related to if stetements is related to not properly indenting code. [This is a pretty good explanation](https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-indentation-auto-indent/) on how to do it in VBA.